# Ubuntu server-sysadmin package-managment docs: best to read Debian's docs?  Any Ubuntu-specific?

Tags: server, package-management, debian, documentation

1. Where's the authoritative, canonical (no pun intended) Ubuntu software-package-management ("pkg-man" for short) docs, references?
2. Similarly, where would one point a newbie sysadmin to canonical Ubuntu pkg-man docs?  Mostly interested in *server-sysadmin, cmdline-oriented usage* (eg: `apt-get` over Synaptic).

**Details, background, related questions**

Noticed these Debian pkg-man docs, references:

- http://wiki.debian.org/PackageManagement
- http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html

Questions:

- Are the above authoritative and canonical (no pun intended) for Debian?
- Do these docs completely apply to Ubuntu?
- Do any related, Ubuntu-specific docs exist?  Possibly presenting diffs between Debian, Ubuntu pkg-man systems, if any?

Answer (score 1):

On [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/).

Specifically, here's a link to the article on [package-management for 12.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/package-management.html).

> Are the above authoritative and canonical (no pun intended) for Debian?

The debian-reference book is. The wiki probably has some good links.

I'd also recommend the recently released [Debian Administrator's Handbook](http://debian-handbook.info/) (which isn't Debian documentation but was written by a Debian Developer and is fairly broad).

> Do these docs completely apply to Ubuntu?

Almost completely. The major differences are that Ubuntu has:

- the main/universe split,
- a different release processes,
- more stable releases available at any given time, and
- `update-manager` for upgrading between releases, where Debian has long release notes, explaining how to do it by hand.

> Do any related, Ubuntu-specific docs exist?

See [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/).

> Possibly presenting diffs between Debian, Ubuntu package management systems, if any?

Not that I know of. But the differences are so small...